# Partition encryption vs symbolic links

Tags: disk-encryption

I'm considering to create a encrypted partition to store some documents and programs using Dm-crypt + Luks. Let's say it will be mounted on `/mnt/secret`.

My question is: is it safe to have symbolic links in my plain partitions pointing to files in `/mnt/secret`?

My apps will also store paths to `/mnt/secret`, for example, list of recently used documents.

Comment: Well, this _will_ leak file names...

Comment: For me, leaking file names is ok. I don't want to leak file contents.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how operating systems work, not about cryptography. It would be on-topic on [unix.se] or [security.se] (but please do not repost!).

Comment: You should also encrypt all partitions where your OS stores temporary data, including swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symbolic link is essentially just a special kind of pseudo-file containing the target path. There is no information about the contents, size, etc., of the target file.

Besides **leaking names of encrypted files**, there should be no problem with having symbolic links to an encrypted partition — security-wise, it is equivalent to a text file containing the target path.

Comment: Thank's. Maybe would you know if the same is true for eCryptFS or EncFS? I'm concerned of leaking file contents rather than file names. These tools encrypt file names and contents individually.

Comment: @arnaldocan Yes, that answer applies no matter what the encryption mechanism is. It's about how symlinks work, not about how the encryption framework works.